# Making an ajax call from a file that's included in many pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple call from a file that's included in various pages.

```
$.post( "wp-content/themes/biagetti_studio/inc/HandleBackground.php", {color:color} );
```

The problem is that i thought that the call was relative to path of the file that include the js (all the files that are including the js are in the same directory), but i discovered that it's relative to the current path, so that if i'm in `localhost/biagettistudio` then the script calls `localhost/biagettistudio/wp-content/themes/biagetti_studio/inc/HandleBackground.php` but if i'm in `localhost/biagettistudio/projects` it calls `localhost/biagettistudio/projects/wp-content/themes/biagetti_studio/inc/HandleBackground.php`.

i know i could put an absolute path

```
$.post( "/wp-content/themes/biagetti_studio/inc/HandleBackground.php", {color:color} );
```

but this presents a problem if i have to port the site were the base directory is not the root. What am i obviously missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    echo "var theme_dir ='" . get_theme_root() . ‘/’ . get_template() ."';";
    ?>
</script>
```

in footer.php (so it's available on every page) and you wouldn't have to worry about breaking stuff if you port the site.

You can then call the script like this...

```
$.post( theme_dir + "/biagetti_studio/inc/HandleBackground.php", {color:color} );
```

Comment: In the end i did something like you suggested but i used `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` (your code lacked the `'` to surround the javascript variable, i added them!

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
var path = location.pathname.match(/(.*)\/wp-content\/.*/)[1];
$.post( path + "/wp-content/themes/biagetti_studio/inc/HandleBackground.php", {color:color} );
```